# Was the oxygen mask, on this flight, out of order?

Tags: oxygen-mask, embraer-e-jet

[image: Button, with red marker, sticking out of oxygen mask panel]

Recently I was on flight where the panel for the oxygen mask, above my seat, looked like on the picture: the "button" in the middle of the panel was extended, turned and was showing a red tag on the side.

I asked a member of the cabin crew if this indicated a problem and the response - after he had tried to turn and push it in - was "I don't know, I don't think so". The fact that he couldn't turn it, or push it back into the panel, makes me think that it is more than just a locking mechanism, that it might have indicated that the system was out of order and I should've moved to a different seat.

Was my hunch correct, does this indicate a faulty oxygen mask?

The plane was an Embraer 190.

Comment: That panel looks too big to be one of the trap doors for the oxygen masks.

Comment: Looking at this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMZQYJ9ASew, confirms that it is the door for the oxygen mask. Around the 1:10 mark you can even see the button that's extended on my picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [Airbus training manual](https://www.slideshare.net/evanildoleal/35-oxygen), pages 10 and 11, that's the test door stop.

As you can see in the video you added, resetting the masks is a pain, so the little red stop is there to catch the door and stop it from fully opening.

> Manually operated doors stops are fitted on the container doors to allow an operational test of the mask release system.
>   When set to test position the door stops will prevent doors from fully opening and masks from dropping out of the Container.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks, that solves the mystery :) 

So basically the door for my oxygen mask was in test mode - a little concerning that the cabin crew did not know this! 

This also answers my other question that, yes, I should've moved to another seat.

Comment: Here's some question regarding the ramifications of not putting on an oxygen mask: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34159/567 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2054/567